# Sending multiple REST calls at once

Tags: rest, get

I want to send multiple simple REST calls at once using different user credentials.
For example, I want to send the following GET request 10 times: "http://localhost/ALS/api/risto/1.0/ElementMappings", using basic authentication (username/password). All requests should be made using different credentials, and all requests should be sent at the exact same time.
I need to test the handling of concurrent requests.

Is there any tool that may help me in achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for any of the automated testing frameworks with decent HTTP support -- for example, [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).